# How to read the ID from a NFC tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nfc

I'm making a C# ASP.NET MVC Webapplication in Visual Studio 2013 and I want to combine it with the NFC technology. I'm working on Windows 8.1.

I possess 2 types of NFC tags (don't know which types) and 2 NFC readers (ASK LoGO RDR608 and my Nexus 5 phone).

I have no idea how I can access the NFC reader in C#/VS and how I can use it to read data from a NFC tag. I tried implementing the "NDEF Library" (that can be found in NuGet) and testing the test application that is available on the website of NDEF. But after executing the Windows 8.1 demo, I click on "Initialize NFC" and I get the error message: "Failed to initialize proximity device".

So does anyone know the best method to use the NFC reader in C# and access/process the data from a NFC tag?

Comment: If you have a web application going, you should look at how to read it from a browser (ala javascript)

Comment: Your best bet is to go with a device vendor who supplies an SDK. Also, if you want to use this in a web context, you're stuck with Internet Explorer and Hosted WinForms.